For $A_t= B_t^l Y_t \mathbb{E}(\frac{A_T}{B_T^l Y_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t)$, find the values of $l$ to replicate $A_t$ by a self financing portfolio $X$
Background:
In attempting to resolve the below problem, I have arrived at an answer that appears to counter intuition (and therefore, I suspect that it is wrong). I would appreciate assistance in either confirming that this approach is correct and, if not, where it goes wrong and how to correct it.
Fix a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ supporting a one dimensional Brownian motion $W$ in its natural filtration. And consider a market with two primary assets:
$$dB_t = r_t B_t dt  \quad B_0 = 1$$ Next is the risky stock:
$$dY_t = (r_t + \vartheta_t^2)Y_t dt + \vartheta_t Y_t dW_t \quad Y_0 > 0$$
And any self-financing replicating portfolio satisfies the dynamics:
$$dX_t = r_t X_t dt + N_t \vartheta_t^2 Y_t dt + N_t \vartheta_t Y_t dW_t \quad X_0 > 0$$ where $N_t$ is the number of shares of the risky asset held at time $t$.
Question:

Consider an asset with price $(A_T)$ at time $T$ such that $A_T \ge 0$.
$$ A_t = B_t^l Y_t \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{A_T}{B_T^l Y_T} \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right) $$
where $l \in \mathbb{R}$. Determine all values of $l$ such that there exists an initial endowment $X_0$ and a self-financing portfolio strategy characterized by $N$ such that $X$ satisfies $X_t = A_t$.

My Approach:

The self-financing portfolio $(X_t)$ must satisfy: $X_t = A_t = B_t^l Y_t M_t$ where $M$ is the conditional expectation above.

By rearranging, we have:$\frac{X_t}{B_t^l} = Y_t M_t$

Using Itô's product rule on both sides and comparing:


$$ d(Y_t M_t) = Y_t K_t \, dW_t + M_t (r_t + \theta_t^2) Y_t \, dt + M_t \theta_t Y_t \, dW_t + K_t \theta_t Y_t \, dt$$
And
$$ d\left(\frac{X_t}{B_t^l}\right) = -\frac{l r_t X_t}{B_t^{l+1}} \, dt + \frac{1}{B_t^l} \left(r_t X_t + N_t \theta_t^2 Y_t \right) \, dt + \frac{1}{B_t^l} N_t \theta_t Y_t \, dW_t$$

Comparing coefficients:

Diffusion terms:



$$Y_t K_t + M_t \theta_t Y_t = \frac{1}{B_t^l} N_t \theta_t Y_t$$
$$ \iff N_t = \frac{B_t^l}{\theta_t} (K_t + M_t \theta_t) $$

Drift terms:

$$M_t (r_t + \theta_t^2) Y_t + \theta_t Y_t K_t = \frac{1}{B_t^l} \left( (1-l) r_t X_t + N_t \theta_t^2 Y_t \right)$$
Substituting $X_t = B_t^l Y_t M_t$ and $N_t = \frac{B_t^l}{\theta_t} (K_t + M_t \theta_t)$:
$$M_t (r_t + \theta_t^2) + \theta_t  K_t = \left( (1-l) r_t M_t + (K_t + M_t \theta_t) \theta_t \right)$$
This seems to only have a solution when $l=0$. But that intuitively does not feel right. Is it really the case that discounting by the risky asset in this way is the only way to ensure that there exists a valid replicating portfolio strategy? Typically we discount by the state-price density $\zeta_t = \frac{B_t}{L_t}$.
